# Php to Parse XML and evaluate multiple lines to set separate variables

Tags: php, xml, parsing, variables

I am trying to load an XML file, and then evaluate 2 different specific tags in the xml and pull the strings into variables.. I am able to get the variables to work but i am unable to do functions that require both variables because something is being written over..

This is where i load the xml file...

```
$test1 = file_get_contents('testfile1.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($test1);
```

This is where i evaluate the different lines..

```
//line1

$domx1 = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries1 = $domx1->evaluate("//dominant_period_sec");

$periodArray = array();
foreach ($entries1 as $entry1) {

$wavePeriod = $entry1->nodeValue;
}

//line2

$domx2 = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries2 = $domx2->evaluate("//dominant_wind_dir");


$avgwaveHeightArray = array();
foreach ($entries2 as $entry2) {

$waveFeet = $entry2->nodeValue;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add this as a comment, because it's not really an answer, but I don't have the privs.

If that's a well-formed XML file, why are you using loadHTML?  Why not:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->load('testfile1.xml');
```

?

I'd guess the answer is:

The variables $wavePeriod and $waveFeet are getting overwritten within the for loops, because you're overwriting them : ).  You could try pushing each item into an array, or something similar - maybe concatenate them.  Something like this, maybe?

```
$waveFeet = array();
foreach ($entries2 as $entry2) {
array_push($waveFeet, $entry2->nodeValue);
}
```

or

```
$waveFeet = '';
foreach ($entries2 as $entry2) {
$waveFeet .= $entry2->nodeValue;
}
```